# Content Inside Parenthesis Regular Expression Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, parentheses

I'm trying to take out the the content inside the parenthesis. For example, if the string is "(blah blah) This is stack(over)flow", I want to just take out "(blah blah)" but leave "(over)" alone. I'm trying

```
    /\A\(.*\)/
```

but returns "(blah blah) This is stack(over)", and I'm sure why it's returning that.

Comment: by "take out" do you mean remove it from the string, or get `blah blah` as match data

Comment: remove from string, sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 1):

Easiest fix:

```
/\A\(.*?\)/
```

Normally, `*` will try to match as much as it possibly can, so it'll match all the way to the last `)` in the line.  This is called "greedy" matching.  Putting `?` after `+`/`*`/`?` makes them *non*-greedy, and they'll match the *shortest* possible string.

But note that this won't work for nested parentheses.  That's rather more complicated.  Given your example, I assume this is for a pretty simple ad-hoc format where nesting isn't a concern.

Comment: Also note, to remove the first occurrence, you could do: `"(blah blah) This is stack(over)flow".sub(/\(.*?\)/, '')`